# Counting Thrown Exceptions

Tags: java, class, exception, count, throw

I have a WelcomeException class and I have thrown my exception, but now I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of times that exception is thrown and then print the count.

Here is the code:

```
public class WelcomeException extends Exception {

    public WelcomeException( String message ) {
         super( message );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class WelcomeException extends Exception {
    private static int count = 0;
    private static final Object countLock = new Object();

    public WelcomeException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
        synchronized(countLock)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static int getCount()
    {
        return count; //atomic. Doesn't need synchro.
    }
}
```

Your comment on another answer:

> Now if I want to print the count in my error message to look this: I
>   know I put: Error printing message {count} times how might I go about
>   that? I'm sorry if this question is basic. I'm very new.

To do this, override the `getMessage()` method like so:

```
public String getMessage()
{
    return 
          super.getMessage() + 
          ", This exception has occurred " + 
          getCount() + 
          " times";
}
```

Comment: @fge I personally prefer synchro primitives. It allows me to understand my program more (I learned synchro from the low level up).

Comment: Uhm, OK, but no, `.getCount()` is not atomic here

Comment: @fge elaborate please

Comment: Two threads A and B; in time order: A gets lock; B gets count; A increments count; A unlocks <-- B hasn't accounted for A's `new()`. And this is only with two threads. Now imagine A1, A2 etc vs B.

Comment: @fge That doesn't matter. No amount of synchonization will fix that. Synchronization guarentees the consistency of the object. The order the things got the lock here was arbitrary anyway. If the method was synchronized, from the public api point of view, the same problem can happen

Comment: It _does_ matter to me. You are 100% thread safe or 0%. Given the current code, not only will `.getCount()` return the wrong information, but `.getMessage()` will be returning wrong data as well

Comment: @fge given 2 threads, assuming all calls at the same time, and full synchronization, the following time scheduling causes the same problem: `B gets count, A gets lock, A increments count, A unlocks` This will have the same effect, and can happen using the same public calls at the same time.

Comment: @fge `Data synchronization refers to the idea of keeping multiple copies of a dataset in coherence with one another, or to maintain data integrity. ` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)

Comment: @fge By all means, provide me some synchronization, that says if getCount is called at the same time as a new Exception is created, that it will be guaranteed that the increment happens first.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static variable (*class variable*) to count the times the exception is being thrown:

```
private static int count = 0;
```

and increase it in the constructor

```
public WelcomeException(String message) {
    super(message);
    count++;
}
```

so it will increase when you throw the exception like

```
throw new WelcomeException("...");
```

Then you can define a getter method:

```
public static int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

and print the result like:

```
System.out.println("WelcomeException has been thrown " + WelcomeException.getCount() + " times.");
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Now if I want to print the count in my error message to look this: I know I put: Error printing message {count} times how might I go about that? I'm sorry if this question is basic. I'm very new.

Comment: For a thread safe version use `AtomicInteger` instead of `int` then you can `count.increment()`

Comment: oops. I put:  throw( new WelcomeException( "Error printing message " ) ); But how do I add the count?

Comment: Okay! Any reason why I am not getting a space in between message and the count? My print result is giving me this output: Error printing message0 times.

Comment: If you add an space it must show an space. Check if you have an space there.

Comment: If you want to have this for each message you should really modify the message at build time: `super(String.format("%s (%d times)", message, count.get()));` <-- supposes `count` is an `AtomicInteger` for thread safety